# Define local path of JSON file in assets folder as URL instead of remote hosted file

Tags: android, json, android-fragments

I want to replace here to a method to execute in android.
String url = "http://hostsitename:8080/filename.json";

Answer (score 0):

Under the res folder, create a raw folder and put your file like example.json.
Then access to the json file like this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = null;

InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.example);

BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line;
try {
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line).append("\n");
    }
    bufferedReader.close();

    jsonObject = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
} catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
     Log.e("tag", "error", e);
}
```